# Switch functions dynamically from shared component

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2

I've created a shared component which handles user registration and log-in.
The problem is `(click)=this[functionName]()` calls collide with two different pages.

For example, when I click a `signup` button from `signup page`, it calls `login method` **first** from time to time. I guess changing function name dynamically like the code below was a wrong approach.

How can I fix this problem? Are there any better ways to change button labels and methods for each page from the shared component?

**RegistrationFormComponent**

```
export class RegistrationFormComponent {

  submitLabel: string;
  functionName: string;

  public handleDynamicSubmitFunc(funcName: string) { this.functionName = funcName; }

  public changeSumitButtonLabelTo(text: string) { this.submitLabel = text; }

  async login() { ... }
  async signup() { ... }
}
```

`<button ion-button block [disabled]="!userEmail.valid || !userPassword.valid" (click)="this[functionName]()">{{ submitLabel }}</button>`

**Signup page**

```
import { RegistrationFormComponent } from "../components/registration-form/registration-form";

export class SignupPage {

  @ViewChild(RegistrationFormComponent) registrationForm: RegistrationFormComponent;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {}

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    this.registrationForm.changeSumitButtonLabelTo('Sign Up');
    this.registrationForm.handleDynamicSubmitFunc('signup');
  }
}
```

**Login page**

```
import { RegistrationFormComponent } from "../components/registration-form/registration-form";

export class LoginPage {

  @ViewChild(RegistrationFormComponent) registrationForm: RegistrationFormComponent;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {}

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    this.registrationForm.changeSumitButtonLabelTo('Log In');
    this.registrationForm.handleDynamicSubmitFunc('login');
  }
}
```

Comment: why not just emit the click event as output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Output` decorator to listen to your shared component.

In shared component html,

```
<button ion-button block [disabled]="!userEmail.valid || !userPassword.valid" (click)="submit()">{{ submitLabel }}</button>
```

In the corresponding ts file,

```
export class RegistrationFormComponent {
    @Output() onSubmit = new EventEmitter<any>();

    submit(){
       this.onSubmit.emit({email:this.email,password:this.password});//pass the values as an object
    }
}
```

In your parent component e.g Signup,

html:

```
<registration-form (onSubmit)="signup($event)"></registration-form><!-- receive event -->
```

and ts:

```
export class SignupPage {

   signup($event){
       //access as $event.email and $email.password
       //...
   }
}
```

Comment: I'm getting `createUserWithEmailAndPassword failed: First argument "email" must be a valid string` error. Both email and password values are undefined. Any ideas?

Comment: @JeffMinsungKim not really.. sounds like a validation issue.. not pertaining to any of the code snippets in the question..

Comment: This is because, both email and password fields are not passing the values. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: they are in the shared component? you can emit through output

Comment: Email and password field are in the shared component, But how can I emit an output to signup and login methods?

Comment: Thank you, It works :) I've changed some portion of your code.

Comment: Should I just keep the changing label method? Or are there any better ways?

Comment: which label method? I didnt get you

Comment: `this.registrationForm.changeSumitButtonLabelTo('Sign Up');` It seems inefficient workaround to me.

Comment: you can use Input decorator to send the label.. either way works

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#pass-data-from-parent-to-child-with-input-binding

Comment: I guess using an input decorator looks better. I really appreciate your help :) Thank you again!